# How to have Git branch name as variable in pom.xml for Dependency Version

Tags: java, git, maven, jar, merge

So my question is...how do I use the branch name I am currently in as part of the version for a dependency in my project?

To start off here is what I have.

I have three branches. master, Alpha and Beta.

Under each of these there is a common dependency being used called automation-jar.jar .... There are also two other client projects that use that jar file as a dependency.

Example: 
   automation-jar pom.xml file

```
<groupId>com.example.jarfile</groupID>
<artifactId>example-jar</artifactId>
<version>${branch.name}-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Example: client project 1 - pom.xml (Uses automation-jar as a dependency)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example.jarfile</groupID>
  <artifactId>example-jar</artifactId>
  <version>${branch.name}-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I can deploy the jar file with the specified "branch.name" no problem....My problem is, how do I make the version snapshot generic enough where it won't cause merge conflicts in Git?

For instance, if I hard code the `<version>` to `master-SNAPSHOT` or `Alpha-SNAPSHOT`, it will cause conflicts when merging the branches.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to include the following plugin

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you can use ${scmBranch} for branchName

http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example.jarfile</groupID>
  <artifactId>example-jar</artifactId>
  <version>${scmBranch}-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) on project alcon-salesforce-etl: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create failed: The scm url cannot be null. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]